# Image quality loss

Tags: asp.net, html, css, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

I had a website running on ASP.NET 4.0. For certain reasons, I had to convert it to ASP.NET 3.5.
Everything is working fine except that some images that I have used on the site are now blurred.
The images are a little larger than the "height=40px" that I have specified, but earlier it was scaling down properly and now the scaled down version is blurred.
The only change is the .NET framework. Is it possible because of that? And how can I resolve it?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: are the images generated by asp.net?

Comment: @DanielA.White I didn't know asp.net also generates images

Comment: no, they are in a folder in the server directory, im just using css to reduce the height to 40px.

Answer (score 0):

check here how to resize images with out losing quality

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/how-to-resize-size-image-without-losing.html